# Representations of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ ($\mathfrak{so}(2,1)$) and $SO(3)$ ($SO(2,1)$)

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

(Apologies if this question is too basic!)  I have explicit 5-dimensional real representations of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ and $\mathfrak{so}(2,1)$, and I want to know whether it's necessarily true that the Lie groups generated by exponentiating these particular Lie subalgebras of $\mathfrak{gl}(5)$ are, in fact, embedded copies of $SO(3)$ and $SO(2,1)$, respectively, in $GL(5)$.  These particular subalgebras are contained in the standard representations of $SO(5)$ and $SO(3,2)$, respectively, but I don't know whether that's sufficient to answer the question.

Comment: Are the representations irreducible?

Comment: I think so, but I'll have to check to make sure.

Comment: SO(3) and SO(2,1) don't have any normal discrete subgroups, so they'd have to be embedded if they aren't trivial.  The greater danger is that they might exponentiate to SU(2) = Spin(3) or SL(2,R) = Spin(2,1) rather than to SO(3) or SO(2,1).  Since both SU(2) and SO(3) sit in SO(5), you haven't yet given us enough information to answer the question.  If they *are* irreducible, then, yes, they are embedded copies of SO(3) or SO(2,1) (actually, the identity component of the latter), since each of these has only one 5-dimensional irreducible representation.

Comment: Robert - thanks much!  They do appear to be irreducible, so hopefully that answers my question.  But I'm curious - how does irreducibility eliminate the other possibilities?

Comment: The obvious 2-dimensional real representaiton of SL(2,R) is not a representation of SO(2,1).  So if your representation were, say, the direct sum of that representation and a trivial 3-dimensional representation or the direct sum of two copies of that representation and a trivial one-dimensional representation, it would still satisfy all the properties that you mentioned, but not be a representation of SO(2,1).

Comment: @JeanneClelland:  Well, up to isomorphism, there is only one irreducible $5$-dimensional representation of ${\frak{so}}(3)$, which exponentiates to a representation of $SO(3)$, and only one irreducible $5$-dimensional representation of ${\frak{so}}(2,1)$, which exponentiates to a representation of the identity component of $SO(2,1)$.

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense.  Thanks to both of you!

Comment: If it is 5 dimensional and irreducible then it is the so-called the spin $s=2$ representation by Physicists or the heighest weight 4 representation by Mathematicians ($d= 2s+1$). Integer spin (or even hw) exponentiate to a true representation of $SO(3)$ while the others give a true represenation of $Spin(3)=SU(2)$.